# How to use dynamic year values as row headers in a Google LineChart

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

I need to create a dynamic Google linechart, displaying the last 5 years montly sales. The months should be on the x-axis and the years be rowheaders. The chart shall display the at any time last 5 years, wherefore the row headers needs to be dynamically created, and I am for that using new Date().getFullYear().

I have the following script:

`

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            var yearnow = new Date().getFullYear();
            var yearnow1 = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
            var yearnow2 = new Date().getFullYear() - 2;
            var yearnow3 = new Date().getFullYear() - 3;
            var yearnow4 = new Date().getFullYear() - 4;

            function drawChart() {
                JSONArray = <%=JSONArray%>;
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONArray);
                data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
                data.addColumn('number', yearnow);
                data.addColumn('number', yearnow1);
                data.addColumn('number', yearnow2);
                data.addColumn('number', yearnow3);
                data.addColumn('number', yearnow4);
                for (var i = 0; i < JSONArray.data.length; i++) {
                    console.log(JSONArray.data[i])
                    data.addRow([JSONArray.data[i].Month, JSONArray.data[i].yearnow, JSONArray.data[i].yearnow1, JSONArray.data[i].yearnow2, JSONArray.data[i].yearnow3, JSONArray.data[i].yearnow4]);
                };

                var options = {
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: 'right',
                    lineWidth: 6,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    axisTitlesPosition: 'out',
                    height: '600',
                    animation: {
                        startup: true,
                        duartion: 5000
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Sale', 
                        viewWindow: {
                            min: 0
                        },
                    },
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Month'
                    }
                    
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>`
```

The data loaded from a JSONarray is:

```
   ` {
  "Month": "1",
  "2023": 41634,
  "2022": 90106,
  "2021": 147584,
  "2020": 79819,
  "2019": 65378
},
{
  "Month": "2",
  "2023": 245165,
  "2022": 250498,
  "2021": 184571,
  "2020": 213433,
  "2019": 81678
},
{
  "Month": "3",
  "2023": 439074,
  "2022": 134073,
  "2021": 448196,
  "2020": 242694,
  "2019": 208779
},
{
  "Month": "4",
  "2023": 107062,
  "2022": 263074,
  "2021": 303642,
  "2020": 147685,
  "2019": 214490
},
{
  "Month": "5",
  "2023": 240823,
  "2022": 120978,
  "2021": 398479,
  "2020": 347350,
  "2019": 366451
},
{
  "Month": "6",
  "2023": 181304,
  "2022": 402940,
  "2021": 232673,
  "2020": 502613,
  "2019": 413191
},
{
  "Month": "7",
  "2023": 197822,
  "2022": 14416,
  "2021": 103021,
  "2020": 114169,
  "2019": 192194
},
{
  "Month": "8",
  "2023": null,
  "2022": 265599,
  "2021": 218532,
  "2020": 67799,
  "2019": 112263
},
{
  "Month": "9",
  "2023": null,
  "2022": 123882,
  "2021": 107786,
  "2020": 133189,
  "2019": 104443
},
{
  "Month": "10",
  "2023": null,
  "2022": 27273,
  "2021": 78118,
  "2020": 122484,
  "2019": 89880
},
{
  "Month": "11",
  "2023": null,
  "2022": 88849,
  "2021": 302903,
  "2020": 145062,
  "2019": 161313
},
{
  "Month": "12",
  "2023": null,
  "2022": 180590,
  "2021": 62515,
  "2020": 83219,
  "2019": 174968
}
```

]
};`

However, the data is not laoding. The chart looks like this:
[image]

Any hints to make the chart data displaying would be much appreciated.